# Styling <use> instances of an SVG symbol

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

The intended effect of the code below is that it displays 2 red circles that turn to gray if the mouse hovers over them.
The Javascript code is inside the SVG for a specific reason and I like to keep it like that.
This specific reason is that I have to live with the way Inkscape symbol sets work.

```css
.hovered {
  fill: gray !important; /* Apply the gray fill color */
  stroke: blue !important; /* Add a blue border */
  stroke-width: 8px !important; /* Set border width */
}
```

```html
<!-- JavaScript class for managing general behavior -->

<!-- SVG containing the symbol -->
<svg style="display: none;">
  <symbol id="redCircle" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="red" />
    <script><![CDATA[   
      // Wait for the document to be fully loaded before setting up event listeners
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
        // Add mouseover and mouseout event handlers to each <use> element
        const useElements = document.querySelectorAll('[*|href="#redCircle"]');
        useElements.forEach(useElement => {
          const color = useElement.getAttribute('data-color') || 'red';
          useElement.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
            console.log("hover");
            useElement.classList.add('hovered');
          });

          useElement.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
            useElement.classList.remove('hovered');
          });
        });
      });
    ]]></script>
  </symbol>
</svg>

<!-- SVG containing two <use> references to the symbol with color properties -->
<svg id="svg-container">
  <use xlink:href="#redCircle" id="use1" x="100" data-color="blue" />
  <use xlink:href="#redCircle" id="use2" data-color="green" />
</svg>
```

If I remove the `fill="red"` from the symbol it does what I want.
but I want the code to work regardless of the `"fill="` attribute of the symbol.

So, here is some stuff I tried:

```
This CSS works, but only if I don't apply fill="red" to the symbol: 
<style>
.hovered {
  fill: gray; /* Apply the gray fill color */
  stroke: blue; /* Add a blue border */
  stroke-width: 8px; /* Set border width */
}
</style>

This CSS doesn't work at all:
<style>
.hovered circle {
  fill: gray; /* Apply the gray fill color */
  stroke: blue; /* Add a blue border */
  stroke-width: 8px; /* Set border width */
}
</style>

This CSS doesn't work at all:
<style>
/* CSS to define the hovered class */
.hovered use circle {
  fill: gray; /* Apply the gray fill color */
  stroke: blue; /* Add a blue border */
  stroke-width: 8px; /* Set border width */
}
</style>

and this CSS is the only one that can override the fill="red":
<style>
circle {
  fill: gray; /* Apply the gray fill color */
  stroke: blue; /* Add a blue border */
  stroke-width: 8px; /* Set border width */
}
</style>
```

Some of you have requested that I elaborate on why I'm "overcomplicating".

- The web-page will eventually be put on a microcontroller, so it must be tiny.
- The SVG symbols with their JS code will be put in a library (Inkscape symbol set) and used as components to create a Human Machine Interface (HMI).
- These components will be notified of state-changes via MQTT over web-sockets
- Once the components are made, all I want to do is 1: Put components in a drawing. 2:Load a configuration file that tells each component which MQTT-messages to act on.
- The components will then "know" what to do if they receive a state change because of the code inside of it.

Hope that helps...

Comment: `'[*|href="#redCircle"]'` selects everything (`*`) or elements with a specific `href` attribute. Seems like the latter half of that selector is redundant...

Comment: It has to do with the xlink:href instead of href.

Comment: I'm no expert but [this is a nice article](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2015/07/16/styling-svg-use-content-css/)

Comment: Indeed it is! I've read it several times!

Comment: I don't think you can do it without also setting the default (red) color as a css property.  If that's ok, try `#svg-container { fill: red; }` and `circle { fill: inherit; }`

Comment: resetting the fill color as suggested by James should do the trick. be careful, when using xlink:href you should also add the `xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"` namespace attribute – or switch to `href` (or for best backwards-compatibility add both). See [codepen example](https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/eYoNoWW). You may also use css variables if your main goal is to set individual hover styles. [example2](https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/qBwdGBg)

Comment: @James ufortunately that is not what I'm looking for no...

Comment: @herrstrietzel thanks for the tip! I'll certainly add this...

Comment: @herrstrietzel That's much nicer to put the fill:red on the use instead of the parent as I tried.

Comment: @HereticMonkey `[*|attr]` is an element that has an attribute `attr` defined in any namespace.

Comment: Please clarify: 1. why you need any JS at all 2. why you can't just drop the fill attribute in the symbol. 3. why you're using the namespaced `xlink:href`  attribute 4. what's this data attribute supposed to do? From your current description most SO members will assume you're just over complicating things. Maybe your ultimate goal is to deploy this svg as an external source with more complex events attached (in this case you'll be facing other issues). So please revise your question.

Comment: *I changed my code so all <use> tags are replaces by <svg> tags, thereby losing the shadow DOM and the restrictions that come with it.*  Pardon me, but you haven't ... please elaborate

Comment: @herrstrietzel I changed my code so all <use> tags are replaces by <svg> tags, thereby losing the shadow DOM and the restrictions that come with it. --> I did do this, but not in my question because that would alter the question to the extend that it is not a question anymore but a work-around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented before predefined fill or stroke attributes (applied to `<symbol>` children) unnecessarily complicate CSS styling `<use>` elements.

### 1. Override via CSS

Provided your asset svg is attached to the DOM – so it can be accessed via CSS rules:
The following example is based on an unchanged HTML/SVG adding CSS overriding rules.

```css
svg{
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  overflow:visible;
}

/* inherit fill */
symbol *{
  fill:inherit;
  stroke:inherit;
}

/* set default fill */
use{
  fill: red; 
}

.hovered {
  fill: gray; 
  stroke: blue; 
  stroke-width: 8px; 
}
```

```html
<!-- SVG containing the symbol -->
<svg style="display: none;">
  <symbol id="redCircle" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="red" />
    <script><![CDATA[   
      // Wait for the document to be fully loaded before setting up event listeners
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
        // Add mouseover and mouseout event handlers to each <use> element
        const useElements = document.querySelectorAll('[*|href="#redCircle"]');
        useElements.forEach(useElement => {
          const color = useElement.getAttribute('data-color') || 'red';
          useElement.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
            console.log("hover");
            useElement.classList.add('hovered');
          });

          useElement.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
            useElement.classList.remove('hovered');
          });
        });
      });
    ]]></script>
  </symbol>
</svg>

<!-- SVG containing two <use> references to the symbol with color properties -->
<svg id="svg-container">
  <use xlink:href="#redCircle" id="use1" x="100" data-color="blue" />
  <use xlink:href="#redCircle" id="use2" data-color="green" />
</svg>
```

Obviously with this approach we can't apply dynamic default fills when changing SVG assets but only a fixed value like "red" – hardcoded in CSS.

### 2. Tweak inline JS

Provided you can fix the embedded JS in your svg assets you may also disable the predefined fill attributes to facilitate CSS styling:

```css
svg{
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  overflow:visible;
}

.hovered {
  fill: gray; 
  stroke: blue; 
  stroke-width: 8px; 
}
```

```html
<!-- SVG containing the symbol -->
<svg style="display: none;">
  <symbol id="redCircle" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="red" />
    <script><![CDATA[   
      // Wait for the document to be fully loaded before setting up event listeners
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
        
        // remove fill from use reference/symbol 
        const symbolEl = document.querySelector('#redCircle circle');
        const symbolElFill = symbolEl.getAttribute('fill');
        symbolEl.removeAttribute('fill');
        
        // Add mouseover and mouseout event handlers to each <use> element
        const useElements = document.querySelectorAll('[*|href="#redCircle"]');
        useElements.forEach(useElement => {
          
          // apply default fill to use elements/symbol instances
           useElement.setAttribute('fill', symbolElFill);

          //const color = useElement.getAttribute('data-color') || 'red';
          useElement.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
            useElement.classList.add('hovered');
          });

          useElement.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
            useElement.classList.remove('hovered');
          });
        });
      });
    ]]></script>
  </symbol>
</svg>

<!-- SVG containing two <use> references to the symbol with color properties -->
<svg id="svg-container" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <use xlink:href="#redCircle" id="use1" x="100" data-color="blue" />
  <use xlink:href="#redCircle" id="use2" data-color="green" />
</svg>
```

Basically we're removing the default fills within the inlined JS like so:

```
// remove fill from use reference/symbol 
const symbolEl = document.querySelector('#redCircle circle');
const symbolElFill = symbolEl.getAttribute('fill');
symbolEl.removeAttribute('fill');
```

### 3. Move the JS logic to a function handling `<use>` instances

In this case we're querying all `<use>` elements, find the referenced defining elements and remove their default styles.

```js
statesForUseInstances();

function statesForUseInstances() {
  // Add mouseover and mouseout event handlers to each <use> element
  const useElements = document.querySelectorAll("use");

  // get element in symbol
  let ref = useElements[0].getAttribute("xlink:href");
  let symboEl = document.querySelector(`${ref}`).children[0];
  
  // remove fill from use reference/symbol
  symboEl.removeAttribute('fill')

  useElements.forEach((useElement) => {
    
    useElement.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
      useElement.classList.add("hovered");
    });

    useElement.addEventListener("mouseout", () => {
      useElement.classList.remove("hovered");
    });
  });
}
```

```css
svg{
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  overflow:visible;
  width:10em;
}

.blue{
  fill: blue;
}

.green{
  fill: green;
}

.hovered {
  fill: gray; 
  stroke: blue; 
  stroke-width: 8px; 
}
```

```html
<!-- SVG containing the symbol -->
<svg style="position:absolute;width:0;height:0;overflow:hidden;visibility:hidden;">
  <symbol id="redCircle" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="red" />    
  </symbol>
</svg>


<!-- SVG containing two <use> references to the symbol with color properties -->
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 100" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <use xlink:href="#redCircle" x="0" width="100" class="blue" />
  <use xlink:href="#redCircle" x="100" width="100" class="green" />
</svg>


<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <use xlink:href="#redCircle" id="use1" class="blue" />
</svg>

<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <use xlink:href="#redCircle" id="use2" class="green" />
</svg>
```

### Recommendations

- avoid predefined styles in `<symbol>` elements
- if you need more advanced JS logic – consider switching to newer, more capable concepts like native Web Components or generate the SVG output completely via JS
- embedding JS in SVG introduces many issues: scripts may be stripped by upload filters because of XSS security measures (for good reasons!) and your app logic is not well maintainable if something changes in you app logic and you need to revise loads of SVG asset files.
- `xlink:href` is classified as deprecated. The main reason you should deploy it is for backwards-compatibility with graphic editors or office applications (which usually don't support more modern SVG standards) – in this case you should also add the namespace attribute to the parent SVG element `xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"`. If your SVG is delivered to browsers only – just replace it with `href`.
- prefer class names assigned to your `<use>` elements for CSS selection to keep your rules' [specificity low](https://css-tricks.com/strategies-keeping-css-specificity-low/). Otherwise you'll end up with too many overriding rules requiring `important!` or nested selectors.

Comment: Idea 2 is brilliant! Never thought of that myself!

Answer (score 2):

You can dump the (oldskool) `symbol` and `use` when you need to **create multiple** SVG objects

Define a **standard** Web Component, creating each SVG and making Events easier

Note: `customElements.define` can also be used **before DOM is parsed**
All `<svg-circle>` will upgrade *automagically*, no `DOMContentLoaded` voodoo required

When you want to go more complex you may want to add a `shadowDOM` so you can scope CSS **and SVG id values**

When you create the SVG with `innerHTML` you do **not** have to set a Namespace. With `createElement` you do have to set the correct SVG NameSpace

```html
<style>
  svg-circle { width: 120px; background: lightgreen; stroke:black }
</style>

<h3>Who is afraid of red, yellow and blue?</h3>

<svg-circle fill="red"    hover="blue" ></svg-circle>
<svg-circle fill="yellow" hover="green"></svg-circle>
<svg-circle fill="blue"   hover="red"  ></svg-circle>
<svg-circle></svg-circle>

<script>
  customElements.define('svg-circle', class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      const fillcolor   = this.getAttribute("fill") || "red";
      this.style.display = "inline-block";
      this.innerHTML     = `<svg viewBox="0 0 9 9">` +
                           `<circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="40%" fill="${fillcolor}"/>` +
                           `</svg>`;
      this.circle = Object.assign(this.querySelector("circle"), {
           style : "cursor:pointer",
           onmouseenter: e => this.fill = this.getAttribute("hover") || "blue",
           onmouseleave: e => this.fill = fillcolor
      })
    }
    set fill(color) {
      this.circle.setAttribute("fill", color);
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you all for your reactions!
However, some of you have missed the fact that I like to keep the Javascript inside of the SVG. That is why I moved this requirement to the top of the question now. Meanwhile I changed my code so all <use> tags are replaces by <svg> tags, thereby losing the shadow DOM and the restrictions that come with it.

Comment: Then Mark that Inkscape comment bold. And note Inkscape spits out bloated SVG code. But yes, sounds like you have to live with that

Answer (score 1):

I have given `id="circleId"` to the red circle.

I am tracking and storing it by `getElementId` under `const redC`.

And modifying the colour by `redC.style.fill= "gray"` on **`mouseover`** and `redC.style.fill= "red"` on **`mouseout`**. Works fine.

```css
    .hovered {
      fill: gray !important; /* Apply the gray fill color */
      stroke: blue !important; /* Add a blue border */
      stroke-width: 8px !important; /* Set border width */
    }
```

```html
    <svg style="display: none;">
      <symbol id="redCircle" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
        <circle id="circleId" cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="red" />
        <script><![CDATA[   
          // Wait for the document to be fully loaded before setting up event listeners
          document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
            // Add mouseover and mouseout event handlers to each <use> element
            const redC= document.getElementById("circleId");
            const useElements = document.querySelectorAll('[*|href="#redCircle"]');
            useElements.forEach(useElement => {
              const color = useElement.getAttribute('data-color') || 'red';
              useElement.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
                console.log("hover");
                useElement.classList.add('hovered');
                redC.style.fill= "gray";
              });

              useElement.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
                useElement.classList.remove('hovered');
               redC.style.fill= "red"; 
              });
            });
          });
        ]]></script>
      </symbol>
    </svg>

    <!-- SVG containing two <use> references to the symbol with color properties -->
    <svg id="svg-container">
      <use xlink:href="#redCircle" id="use1" x="100" data-color="blue" />
      <use xlink:href="#redCircle" id="use2" data-color="green" />
    </svg>
```

Comment: I'm going to try your code ASAP. This is weird...

Comment: @Bigman74066   It actually is weird. Try removing lines from .hovered class and see how it behaves.

Comment: I tried your code, but it doesn't work in (Chrome) what browser are you using?

Comment: @Bigman74066 Chrome. It works fine here. Just checked with Firefox. Firefox greys both the circles, while on chrome only the hovered one changes color. Can you check on Firefox? 
 https://jsfiddle.net/j8pz2xq1/

Comment: @Bigman74066  Checked on mobile (clicking). It works fine on mobile too.

Answer (score 1):

I have modified your code a bit to accomodate my example, removed the JS and introduced `:hover` with CSS custom properties.

As HTML *data attributes* currently can still only be used as stringresults from CSS `attr(..)` I think it would be best to use CSS *custom properties* instead.

*The base principle*

1. At parent level assign generic color variables to be used by child elements:

- `#svg-container { color: red }`, set a default color (sets `currentColor`)
- `#svg-container { --primary: blue; --secondary: --green /* extend at will */ }`, to set required colors. For page wide use, set them at `:root` level.

2. Assign override colors at child level to display time color variable `--dsp-color`:

- `#use1 { --dsp-color: blue }`, a simple, direct override.
- `#use2 { --dsp-color: var(--primary, magenta) }`, default to `magenta` when `--primary` is undefined.
- `#use3 { --dsp-color: var(--secondary, yellow) }`, default to `yellow` when `--secondary` is undefined.
- extend this list as required or use classes instead.
- Instead, the above rules can also be defined in the specific HTML `<use>` as a `style="..."` e.g. `<use id="use1" style="--dsp-color: blue">`, etc.

3. Use display color variable `--dsp-color` to finally display a circle with the required color:

- `circle { fill: var(--dsp-color, currentColor) }`, uses the display time color variable and the current parent `color` value. This sets the appropriate color overriding the `fill` set in a `<circle>` (which essentially has become redundant).

**The snippet** is commented and should be self explanatory combined with the above. I added a few extra variables to show a more generic hover effect.

```css
/*
    Main color definitions
*/
#svg-container {
    /* change to any default color you require, sets 'currentColor' */
    color: red;

    /* disable these to see defaults in effect */
    --primary  : blue;   /* disable to show magenta circle */
    --secondary: green;  /* disable to show yellow circle */
    /**/

    /* Optionally define hover effects */
    --hover    : gray;
    --stroke   : blue;
    --str-width: 8px;
} 
/*
    Specific Color overrides per <use> case
    When undefined, they fallback to a default color
*/
#use1 { --dsp-color: blue }
#use2 { --dsp-color: var(--primary  , magenta) }
#use3 { --dsp-color: var(--secondary, yellow)  }

/*
    Color handling SVG circle
*/
#redCircle circle { /* optionally using #redCircle for more specificity */
    /* When --dsp-color is undefined it defaults to 'currentColor' defined in #svg-container */
    fill: var(--dsp-color, currentColor); /* overrides 'fill' in <circle> */
}

#redCircle circle:hover { /* optionally using #redCircle for more specificity */

    fill  : var(--hover, gray);  /* Apply --hover fill color, default gray */
    stroke: var(--stroke, blue); /* Apply --stroke color, default blue */

    stroke-width: var(--str-width, 8px); /* Apply --str-width, default 8px */

    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<svg style="display: none;">
    <symbol id="redCircle" viewBox="0 0 400 200">
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="red" />
        <!-- 'fill' is redundant here, gets overridden -->
    </symbol>
</svg>

<!-- SVG containing four <use> references to the symbol with color properties -->
<svg id="svg-container" style="">
    <use xlink:href="#redCircle" id="use1" x="0"   />
    <use xlink:href="#redCircle" id="use2" x="75"  />
    <use xlink:href="#redCircle" id="use3" x="150" />
    <use xlink:href="#redCircle" id="use4" x="225" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want the code to work regardless of the "fill=" attribute of the symbol.

Here is a straightforward CSS approach, in which:

1. you apply the `fill` value to the `<use>` elements (via each element's `id`)
2. the `<circle>` inherits the `fill` value from the step above, via `fill: inherit`.

---

**Working Example:**

```css
svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 180px;
}

circle {
  fill: inherit;
}

circle:hover {
  fill: gray;
  stroke: blue;
  stroke-width: 8px;
}

use[href="#redCircle"] {
  fill: red;
}

#use1 {
  fill: blue;
}

#use2 {
  fill: green;
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <defs>
    <symbol id="redCircle">
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" />
    </symbol>
  </defs>

  <g id="container">
    <use id="use1" href="#redCircle" x="0" />
    <use id="use2" href="#redCircle" x="100" />
    <use id="use3" href="#redCircle" x="200" />
    <use id="use4" href="#redCircle" x="300" />
  </g>  
</svg>
```

---

**Further Reading:**

- [Styling SVG  Content with CSS](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2015/07/16/styling-svg-use-content-css/) by Sara Soueidan

Comment: **Added:** It didn't seem like there would be anywhere, where `circle:hover` wouldn't work. So when I wrote this on Firefox, I didn't check cross-browser compatibility. Newsflash: it's entirely unclear why, but  `circle:hover` appears not to work in the Blink rendering engine (Chrome, Edge, Brave etc.)